# How to add a new WebPart in a specific Group after it is deployed

Tags: sharepoint, wss, wss-3.0, web-parts

I am constantly writing custom WebParts but after I deploy them, they always get added to the "Miscellaneous" category. How do I add a WebPart to a specific category?

The category that I am referring to here is the one we see in the "Add Web Parts..." pop up, which is activated when the "Add a Web Part" is clicked on a zone.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update your web part manifest file and add the following:

```
<property Name="Group" Value="Custom" />
```

Follow the instructions [here](http://claytonj.wordpress.com/2009/01/08/how-to-add-a-webpart-into-a-special-group-other-than-miscellaneous/) for details.

Comment: I actually remember adding that tag in the xml file but I think I got the case of the name "Group" wrong... hhmmm

Comment: The reason it did not work earlier is because I added the tag in the wrong file (*.webpart). I added it to *.xml file and it is now working. Thanks